# put two pages and access with one button in android

Tags: android

hello I want put one button . when click that button from this page go to another page. I think I use Relative layout but I don't know exactly how to use it. please put complete code from "main.xml" and "activity" because I'm an amateur!!!  thanks

Comment: "please put complete code because I'm an amateur!!! " that's not the way to phrase a question here.See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I count the seconds until this question goes closing..

Answer (score 0):

Oh silverboy...

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to second page"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```